# Verify if ... is a field - Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I have 2 tasks from fields that I am not able to solve.

As far as I know checking if set is a field is based on checking if it an abelian group with respect to addition and multiplication (without $0$ for invertibility). Am I right?

> Verify if $Q(2^{\frac{1}{3}})$ is a field with respect to ordinary addition and multiplication.
>
> Is $ (R, \#, \Delta) $ a field where, for every $x,y$ from $\Bbb R$, $ x\#y= x+y+1 $ and $x\Delta y = xy+x+y$?

Comment: How did you define $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$? Depending on the given definition, your question is utterly trivial or just trivial.

Comment: To check if something is a field, you have to check that it is a commutative ring in which every non element other than the additive identity has a multiplicative inverse. To verify that something is a commutative ring, you have to check that it has the appropriate group structures for both operations, and that multiplication distributes over addition. Alternatively, you could show that something is a field by showing that it has a field isomorphism to a known field, or that it is a subfield of a known field.

Comment: Your second question is unrelated, so it should be posted (with proper context) in a separate question. It has already been asked and replied, anyway. Since $x\# y = (x+1)+(y+1) -1$ and $x\Delta y=(x+1)\cdot(y+1)-1$ you are just applying a pushforward/pullback to the field structure of $(\mathbb{R},+,\cdot)$.

Comment: I just don't know how to start checking these conditions. When I had an exercise like this
Verify if (R ,*) is a group, where a*b=a b 
It was clear for me what to do, because I was operating on a,b and c.
Now when I have for example Q(2^(1/3)) I don't know how should I start checking, so if you can guide me how to do the first step it would be great.

Comment: @JamesSmith: first step - How is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ defined? You/we cannot prove or disprove that something is a field if we do not know what we are talking about.

Comment: That is the whole task that I was given (100% copied now):
Verify if Q( 3 2 ) is a field with respect to ordinary addition and multiplication. If the answer is YES, verify if it is isomorphic to Q( 2 ).
So maybe it is just incomplete.

Comment: Now I got what you meant. Q = rational numbers.

Comment: Maybe the definition of $\mathbb Q (\alpha)$ was given in class? If not it's a serious omission.

Comment: @JustinYoung Like I wrote a few minutes ago Q = rational numbers. Sorry

Comment: That's not the only thing missing, what does the " $(\alpha)$" mean?

Comment: @JustinYoung On a forum that is in my native language somebody wrote:
Q(3√2) is a set of elements in the form of a+b3√2+c3√4, where a,b,c ∊Q
However myself I don't know nothing more

Comment: That is probably incorrect, notice $c3\sqrt{4}=6c$, it might be better to consult your materials, somewhere there you probably defined this. It is a waste of time to trying to find answer if you dont know the question...

Comment: Your display could be clearer, I think you mean all numbers of the form $a + b \sqrt[3]{2} + c \sqrt[3]{4}$, where $a,b,c\in \mathbb Q$. Now that you have something to check, check the conditions.

Comment: It might be easier to put $\alpha = \sqrt[3]{2}$, and you get all numbers of the form $a + b\alpha + c\alpha^2$.

Comment: The hard part seems to be inverses.

Comment: @JustinYoung I have one more question about 2nd task if I can. 
x#(y#z) it has to be = (x#y)#z
And then
x#(y+z+1)
x+y+z+1+1
Can I do that this way?
Because I remember that on the lecture something like f(x) and f(y) etc. was used but I don't really get that way and I would prefer the one given above by me. Thanks

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio
I am trying now to solve 2nd task and I think that I will easily achieve it. However I am having little trouble coz:
3rd condition for (R,#) to be an abelian group is that it has to be invertible.
And I have something like this:
x#b=e
x+b+1=−1
x= −2−b
And my 'proof' now is the fact that in set of real numbers there has to be one that will make this equation to be true. Am I right? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For the second one, you can shortcut much of the trouble by proving that the map $$ f(x) = x+1 $$ is an *isomorphism* from $(\mathbb R,\#,\Delta)$ to $(\mathbb R,{+},{\cdot})$. When two structures are isomorphic they are either fields both of them or neither is, and $(\mathbb R,{+},{\cdot})$ is well known to be a field.

Comment: Indeed, this is a case of transport of structure, induced by the shift of one unit.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is easy to check while the second one is field which has zero element -1 and identity element 0 and multiplicative inverse of $x$ is ${-x}/{(x+1)}$ and additive inverse of $x$ is $-2-x$.
Solve this $ xy+x+y = 0 $ and $x+y+1 = -1$.